# Excel VBA MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 PUT request fail on "send" action

Tags: excel, vba, jira-rest-api

I'm creating an integration with Jira on Excel using VBA.

I'm able to login securely (using `POST`) and retrieve Jira issues (using `GET`) using Jira's API.

Now I'm trying to update issues, and the HTTP verb on Jira's API is `GET`. This shouldn't be a problem, but the fact is I can't even make the request.

Here's my current code - it's based on the `POST` code, but I'm not sure if I'm missing some other params.

*I'm omitting some variable declarations - this is not the issue!*

```
Public JiraService As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
JiraDataUrl = "https://atlassian.XXXXXXXX.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/" & JiraId
body = "{""fields"" : {""customfield_13800"":""2011-10-03""}}"

Call JiraLogin(user, pass) 'This calls another Sub that log into Jira

JiraService.Open "PUT", JiraDataUrl, False
JiraService.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
JiraService.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
JiraService.setRequestHeader "X-Atlassian-Token:", "nocheck"
JiraService.send body

jsonText = JiraService.responseText
sStatus = JiraService.Status
```

When I run the script, it's interrupted by excel with the following messages:

[image: First alert]

I click on `Debug` and the `JiraService.send body` part is marked on the code

[image: Marked area on the code]

If I click on play, I get the final error (`This method cannot be called after the send method has been called`), that doesn't make any sense to me:

[image: This methodcannot]

If I replace `PUT` for `POST` it runs normally, but Jira API returns with 405 HTTP error - as the method I'm trying to use requires a PUT.

Any idea on what am I doing wrong in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am doing the same thing right now, and I've figured out, that updating an issue requers async connection:

```
JiraService.Open "PUT", URL, True
```

In that case

```
JiraService.send data
```

will be succesful, but `JiraService.status` returns 1223! However, an issue field will be updated...

There is a discussion with the same "problem" with MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 and it seems, 1223 code is a kind of "success code":
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c4911cd8-caba-4c25-b71c-fe2e1a7ef8be/update-sharepoint-list-metadata-using-rest-from-vba-using-msxml2xmlhttp60

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Dmitry. I got the same status code (that makes no sense) and the solution worked perfectly!

Comment: There is another answer with more explanations [here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046972/msie-returns-status-code-of-1223-for-ajax-request)